# Traffic citation

Tags: united-states

So I forgot to turn my headlights on one night and got pulled over. He gave me a warning for the headlights but I didn't have my proof of insurance so I got a traffic citation for that and I went to court on that date that was on it and I'm 16 so the judge said I need to go to juvenile court for it.
So he said the court would send me a date to go to that in about 1-3 weeks well that was 4 months ago and I still haven't got anything. So what do I do?
Also if it helps I live in Savannah Georgia

Comment: Call the court and ask?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not asking anything about the law itself. This seems to be a simple clerical question that should be directed at the office clerk.

Answer (score 2):

As BlueDogRanch said in the comments, just call the clerk's office and ask when your court date is. Have the ticket with you so you can give them the case number.

Comment: And document everything.  Write down the fact that you called a specific number, on a specific date, at a specific time, and you spoke to a specific person, and document exactly what answer they give you.   Its probably worthless now, but you never know when it might become important later on.